# Exibir resultado de um form dinamicamente de uma lista com valores de um JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Gostaria de saber se tem como exibir o resultado na tag

sem a necessidade de um botão, apenas terminando de preencher, e como calcular o resultado pegando a informação do modelo JSON.

Exemplo:
Isa| Acrescimo media: 10% |
Media: 84,66 + 10% |
Total: 93,12

Isa - Total: 93,12

Fiz um teste para validar os campos usando onblur, porem queria que fosse validado se os 3 campos estivessem preenchidos, tentei retornar true apos cada onblur em cada input, porem não deu certo
Alguem teria alguma ideia ?

Grato pela ajuda!

```
    <div>
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="">
        <br>
        <label>Desconto media %:</label>
        <input type="number" name="">
        <br>
        <label>Acrescimo media:</label>
        <select name="nomes">
            <option value="Isa">Isa</option>
            <option value="Paulo" >Paulo</option>
            <option value="Beatriz">Beatriz</option>
        </select>

        <hr>
        <h4>TOTAL: </h4>
        <p></p>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            let text = '{"students":[' +
        '{"name":"Isa","grade1":"80","grade2":"75","grade3":"99" },' +
        '{"name":"Paulo","grade1":"55","grade2":"32","grade3":"80" },' +
        '{"name":"Beatriz","grade1":"85","grade2":"65","grade3":"20" },' +
        ']}';
            const obj = JSON.parse(text);

            nomes.onblur = function() {validacao};

            function validacao() {
            let nome = document.getElementById("nome");
            let desconto = document.getElementById("desconto");
            let nomes = document.getElementById("nomes");

                If (nome != "" && desconto != "" && nomes != ) {
                    alert ("teste");

                    //teste para ver se esta validando 
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui!
Agora so vou adaptar, mas deixo aqui para quem tenha alguma duvida parecida =)

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            let alunos = '{"alunos":[' +
            '{"nome":"Isa","nota1":"90" ,"nota2":"85" ,"nota3":"99" },' +
            '{"nome":"Paulo","nota1":"70" ,"nota2":"53" ,"nota3":"87" },' +
            '{"nome":"Beatriz","nota1":"90" ,"nota2":"55" ,"nota3":"32" }]}';
            

            const objAlunos = JSON.parse(alunos);

            let nome = document.getElementById("nome");
            let acrescimo = document.getElementById("acrescimo");
            let nomes = document.getElementById("nomes");
            let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

            
            nome.onblur = function() {validacao()};
            acrescimo.onblur = function() {validacao()};
            nomes.onblur = function() {validacao()};


            function validacao() {
                if (nome.value != ''  && nomes.value != '' && acrescimo.value != ''){
                    for (var i = 0; i < objAlunos.alunos.length; i++) {
                        if (objAlunos.alunos[i].nome == nomes.value) {
                            let vlrPorc = parseFloat(acrescimo.value)/100;
                            let mediaNota = parseFloat(objAlunos.alunos[i].nota1)+parseFloat(objAlunos.alunos[i].nota2)+parseFloat(objAlunos.alunos[i].nota3)/3;
                            let notaFinal = mediaNota+(mediaNota*vlrPorc);
                            resultado.innerHTML = 'Professor: '+nome.value+' Acrescimo: '+acrescimo.value+'% Nota Final = ' +notaFinal;
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
            
        </script>
```